# What is the proper way of setting flowControl options to existing subscription?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

Documentation did not tell, what is the proper way to use existing subscription with `@google-cloud/pubsub@0.14.x`

Subscriptions can be received with `topic.getSubscriptions()`, but there does not seem to be obious way of setting subscriptions flowControl options for received subscriptions.

Also `topic.createSubscription()` seems to return existing subscription if it is found and there is possibility to pass options object.

So, is there a way of setting flowControl options to received subscription or is createSubscription intended for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the node library "subscription" can refer to one of two things. It can refer to the Cloud Pub/Sub entity, which is the logical entity that is interested in messages on a topic. It can also refer to a worker that receives messages on a logical subscription. We also refer to this worker as a "subscriber." There can be zero or more subscribers running simultaneously to receive messages for a subscription. If there is more than one subscriber, then messages are load balanced across them.

Flow control is a property of a worker, not a Cloud Pub/Sub subscription. In the [documentation for a subscription](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/pubsub/0.14.5/pubsub), it states "note that [flow control] options do not persist across subscription instances." The `createSubscription` method should be used to set flow control settings on a worker. If the subscription entity already exists in Cloud Pub/Sub, then it will not be recreated. The worker created by `createSubscription` will use this subscription and apply the flow control settings that are specified. The [message flow control example](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#subscriber-flow-control-nodejs) demonstrates how to set the properties.

Comment: I asked about this also at Github and it seems we will also get setOptions method to set subscription options.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2723#issuecomment-341993187

Comment: Unfortunately the exact semantics of the "maxMessages" for FlowControl is not described anywhere in the documentation. What does it mean to have maxMessages=0? maxMessages=1? maxMessages=100? etc.

Comment: @RomanKharkovski I believe maxMessages sets the max number of unacked messages a client will have at any time